# Getting a value of checkbox into array when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am working with jQuery and this is my code so far:

```
$('.CategoryInput').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        var CategoryID  = $( this ).attr( "category" );
        var Clicked     = $( this ).attr( "clicked" );
        if(Clicked == 0){
            $("#Category" + CategoryID).css({backgroundColor: '#fc3b66'});
            $("#Category" + CategoryID).find( ".state" ).css({color: '#fff'});
            $(".subcat" + CategoryID).css({backgroundColor: '#fc3b66'});
            $(".subcat" + CategoryID).find( ".state" ).css({color: '#fff'});
            $(".SubCategoryInput" + CategoryID).prop('checked', true);
            $(".SubCategoryInput" + CategoryID).attr('clicked','1');
            $(this).attr('clicked','1');
        } else {                    
            $("#Category" + CategoryID).css({backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd'});
            $("#Category" + CategoryID).find( ".state" ).css({color: '#6a6d76'});
            $(".subcat" + CategoryID).css({backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd'});
            $(".subcat" + CategoryID).find( ".state" ).css({color: '#6a6d76'});
            $(".SubCategoryInput" + CategoryID).prop('checked', false);
            $(".SubCategoryInput" + CategoryID).attr('clicked','0');
            $(this).attr('clicked','0');
        }

        });

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="container">                 
    <h1>Selecciona los productos que elaboras:</h1>
    <?PHP
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Category` WHERE `subCategory`='0' ORDER by Position ASC");
        while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
                {
                $id = $rowi['id'];
                $Name = $rowi['Name'];
                $Description = $rowi['Description'];

    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="maintag" id="Category<?PHP echo $id;?>">
            <label class="state" for="categories"><?PHP echo $Name;?></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="CategoryInput" name="categories" category="<?PHP echo $id;?>" clicked="0">          
            (<?PHP echo $Description;?>)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <?PHP 
        $r1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Category` WHERE `subCategory`='$id' ORDER by Position ASC");
            while($rowi1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1))

            {
                $id1 = $rowi1['id'];
                $Name1 = $rowi1['Name'];                                
    ?>

        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0px;">
            <div id="subtag<?PHP echo $id1;?>" class="subcat<?PHP echo $id;?> supersub">
                <label class="state" for="categories"><?PHP echo $Name1;?></label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="subcategory" class="SubCategoryInput<?PHP echo $id;?>" SubCategory="<?PHP echo $id1;?>" clicked="0">          
            </div>
        </div>  

                <?PHP } ?>
        </div>      
<?PHP } ?>
</div>
```

I have several checkboxes which I use as categories. These categories have sub-categories, so this code is simply highlighting the checkboxes which are selected. If the selected checkbox is from mother category it highlights all the checkboxes for all children categories. Also setting them as `checked`.

Everything I achieved so far as I want. Right now I am stuck on how I can get the id of the selected checkbox and add it into a variable looking like this:

```
var SelectedCategoryIDs = '12,435,123,124,56,34,23';
```

So when I click a mother category it will add to `SelectedCategoryIDs` the ids of all children categories. Also when I uncheck the already checked mother category it will remove all the ids from `SelectedCategoryIDs` which corresponds to all children categories.

So can you help me achieve that?

I hope I explained it well, if you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: can you show us your HTML please?

Comment: Done, check out my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Just make an array and then join it by comma separated:

```
var selectedArray = [];
$('.CategoryInput').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      selectedArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});

/* and then join: */

var selectedString = selectedArray.join(","); // you'll give all ids comma separated
```

Comment: I only add the lines to the original code of the OP. OP is listening onclick event to checkbox when it's better onchange, but nobody said nothing about this...

Comment: clicking an item that's already been clicked is meant to unclick it; the OP accounts for this in their code already

Comment: Your solutions are probably better, but this code is easy to OP and he can improve it

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `click` callback, just add

```js
var SelectedCategoryIDs = '';

$('.CategoryInput').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    // Include the old code here...
    
    // Here's the new part
    SelectedCategoryIDs =
      $('.CategoryInput[clicked=1]')
      .map(function() {
        return this.category;
      })
      .get()
      .join(',');
  });
});
```

Comment: SelectedCategoryIDs is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hrt7cxvp/22/) of what you are trying to achieve. I have used underscore.js along with jquery since I love the utility methods that it offers.

Basically my event handler looks like this. the _.without function basically will return your array without the unchecked value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = [];
$("input:checkbox").on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    arr.push($(this).val());
  }
  else {
    arr = _.without(arr, $(this).val());
  }
  $("#arr").text(arr);
 });
})
```

---

Here is the updated code without underscore js

https://jsfiddle.net/hrt7cxvp/26/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var selectedArray = [];
$("input:checkbox").on("click", function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    selectedArray.push($(this).val());
  }
  else {
    selectedArray.splice(selectedArray.indexOf($(this).val()));
  }
  $("#arr").text(selectedArray);
 });
})
```